# Upgrading Awesomium SDK 1.6.6 to 1.7

Tags: awesomium

I have Awesomium SDK 1.6.6 installed and i want to upgrade it to the 1.7 candidate how could i do that. because when i downloaded the 1.7 i find it is only consists of some files and no setup file included (like the 1.6 one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to use the .NET wrappers? If so, you should be able to download and extract the files anywhere, then in your project, just add references to Awesomium.Core.dll and either Awesomium.Windows.Forms.dll or Awesomium.Windows.Controls.dll, depending on whether you're using Winforms or WPF. The dlls are located in awesomium_1_7_rc3_v3_sdk_win\wrappers\AwesomiumNET\Assemblies\ within the archive.

I believe the setup.exe you're expecting to see is only used for extracting the files to a specific location and providing you with some helpful links in your start menu, so you aren't missing much by not having it.

Answer (score 1):

We have not created an installer for the Release Candidates of version 1.7. RCs are not stable releases. There will be one again when 1.7 goes stable and 1.6.6 installations will then be able to automatically upgrade to 1.7.